# The webpage cannot be found calling Web API Function

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have the following Web API defined

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace MRNInput.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/Appointment")]
    public class AppointmentController : ApiController
    {
        [AcceptVerbs("Post")]
        [Route("GetMissingKeys")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetMissingKeys([FromBody]string MRNList)
        {
            return Ok();
        }

        [AcceptVerbs("Get")]
        [Route("Get")]
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok();
        }

    }
}
```

The following is the Global.asax.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MRNInput
{
    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        }
    }
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs is the following;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace MRNInput
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

I created the Get simply to test routing, Site starts at http://localhost:51520/Default.html - calling http://localhost:51520/api/Appointment/Get and I get The webpage cannot be found

.Net 4.5 application with Web API template used when creating a Web Application. Controller was added by using the Web API Controller - Empty template

Comment: what url you are requesting?

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `[AcceptVerbs]` attribute with `[HttpGet], [HttpPost]` etc. `AcceptVerbs` is the old attribute which is used in WebForms apps. Also if you calling your api from IE and return json it tries to download the result instead of showing it in browser

Comment: Tried that - still giving me Web Page Cannot be found. Using F12 and checking the address called http://localhost:51520/api/Appointment/Get

Comment: In your case you don't need `Route("Get")` attribute. If method name the same as the HTTP method (Get, Post etc) it is unnecessary to set Route attribute. Since that you can only place `HttpGet` attribute and call your method via 'localhost:51520/api/Appointment' url. Web API very similar to MVC, but it has its own differences

Comment: Thanks - tried that as well. It is almost as if the routing is not being setup

Comment: if you want to use AttributeRouting feature, you should not make any additional configurations for it. all that you need is to set the name in the `[Route]` attribute and use this name. in web api if you named your methods as http method verb it is unnecessary to specify routing (e.g. Get(), Post(), Put() Delete()), but if method name is different from htp verb - you must specify routing. you can call your method without routing just calling your method by name in MVC app, but it does not work in web api

Comment: you can read this post about how to use attribute routing in web api http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: Effectively I should have been using Attribute Routing (see WebApiConfig.cs above)  but for some reason it does not seem to be working in this project. I have done it before but cannot see any difference between this and times previous when it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `[Route("")]` to have access to `GET api/Appointment` request.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("")]
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: Thanks - just tried that and it still makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. Still do not know the hows and why. Nothing wrong with the code as such.

Basically it was to do with the way the project was created. Selecting an empty project and clicking the Web API checkbox and you get the problem above. Instead select the Web API in the Select a template icons - this will select both the MVC and Web API checkboxes. I still had problems which required the solution to be cleaned but now it routes correctly.